# ember select: selection computed alias vs value computed alias

Tags: ember.js

I'm wondering if this is a bug or if I'm just missing something...

On an ember.Select you can set the 'selection' to a computed alias and it works.

```
selection: Em.computed.alias('parentView.controller.test3')
```

You can set 'valueBinding' to a path and it works.

```
valueBinding: 'parentView.controller.test2'
```

But you can't set 'value' to a computed alias, that does not work.

```
value: Em.computed.alias('parentView.controller.test')
```

I've included a jsfiddle that demonstrates this on ember latest.  Am I missing something here?  I thought I read that bindings in views were going to be silently deprecated and I've been trying to use Em.computed.alias() instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/3DzzZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `value` on `Ember.Select` is a computed property, and you are overriding that computed property breaking the code-behind

```
/**
In single selection mode (when `multiple` is `false`), value can be used to
get the current selection's value or set the selection by it's value.

It is not currently supported in multiple selection mode.

@property value
@type String
@default null
*/


value: Ember.computed(function(key, value) {
  if (arguments.length === 2) { return value; }
  var valuePath = get(this, 'optionValuePath').replace(/^content\.?/, '');
  return valuePath ? get(this, 'selection.' + valuePath) : get(this, 'selection');
}).property('selection'),
```

whereas `selection` is just a boring property

```
 /**
When `multiple` is `false`, the element of `content` that is currently
selected, if any.

When `multiple` is `true`, an array of such elements.

@property selection
@type Object or Array
@default null
*/


selection: null
```

Comment: value isn't a function that's being called or set in the code listed above,  he is literally overriding the property on the object, it won't ever touch the default implementation in his third troublesome example.